# Java is drawing 2 boxes

Tags: java, swing

So I am making a little game to learn some graphical java and I am having trouble with a button. It is drawing 2, one is the correct size and in the correct location and then there is a very small button centered at the top of the application. THere should only be the one button at (0,0,200,50). I do not know what is wrong but here is the code for the button, if you need something more then this let me know!

```
ImageIcon test = new ImageIcon("nhButton.png");
    JButton jb = new JButton(test);
    jb.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 50);
    jb.setVisible(true);
    add(jb);
```

EDIT1: the 2 classes where error will be: board.java:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Board extends JPanel {


    public Board() { 

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ImageIcon test = new ImageIcon("nhButton.png");
        JButton jb = new JButton(test);
        jb.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 50);
        jb.setVisible(true);
        add(jb);
    }

    private void drawRectangle(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

and the main:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class main extends JFrame {

    public main() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        add(new Board());

        setSize(800, 600);

        setTitle("Application");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                main ex = new main();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that error somewhere else...

Comment: Alright I added both the classes and deleted everything that wasnt relevant.

Comment: Is that `add(jb)` really in `paintComponent()`? If so: what is the intention behind this? Also: `drawRectangle()` is not called anywhere in the code you are showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to resize window, you will see that buttons are spawning.

This happens because of your `paintComponent` method, which is called every painting iteration.

You should move button addition, for example, to constructor which is called once:

```
public Board() {
    ImageIcon test = new ImageIcon("nhButton.png");
    JButton jb = new JButton(test);
    jb.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 50);
    jb.setVisible(true);
    add(jb);
}
```

Comment: ah, so when is paintComponent called?

Comment: Because I have other things in there I just deleted them for the purpose of this post because they were irrelivant

Comment: @user2747058 `paintComponent` is intended to draw component itself and is called from `JComponent#paint`, which also draws borders, background, etc. Window resizing, its components moving/resizing, etc. cause to repaint all window or some part of it.